# How to play world of warships with someone from a different region?

Tags: world-of-tanks, world-of-warships

I am based in Europe, while I have someone I wish to play World of Warships that is based in the United States. How could I play with them?

So far all the answers that I have found indicate that I'd have to download a version of the game for each specific region, but so far I haven't found anything in the Wargaming launcher that shows I can play in a different region:

What I have looked at already:

- [Forum answer from 2015](https://forum.worldofwarships.com/topic/138774-can-i-play-on-both-na-and-eu-servers/) (seems outdated)
- [Wargaming offering to switch account](https://worldofwarships.eu/en/content/server-2-server/) (I want to keep both my account on the EU and an account on the NA servers)

So how can I play in a different region on World of Warships from the server I am on?

PS - I have tagged WoT as this answer may also be applicable to that game due to WoT and WoWS being made by the same company.

Answer (score 2):

You can not play on another server with your EU Account. If you made your Account on EU, you will only be able to play on EU. WarGaming does not offer account transfers to a different Server (**usually**).

If you really want to play on the NA Server, you need to do the following:

1. Make an NA Account.
2. Download the NA Launcher of the Game.
3. Open the NA Launcher and sign in with your NA Account.

After that, you will be able to play on the NA Server.

Obviously, you play on a new Account and that means you have to start from scratch. And don't forget about the bad Ping.

There is currently no other way to do it.

I personally use this method to play WoT on NA Server.

**Edit: 28th September 2022**

Wargaming does offer Account Transfer to another Region, however only at limited times.
You can read more about the Server Transfer [here](https://worldofwarships.eu/en/content/server-2-server/).

[image]

This offer is only available for a limited time, maybe again in the future.